# How do I persist my next-auth user session? so i could use the ID provided to fetch data in other routes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

What I want to achieve here is, whenever a user logs in, I want to store the data returned because the data holds an ID that I would use to fetch data in other routes.
When a user successfully logs in, he would be redirected to the /home route and the ID gotten from the session would be used to fetch data. Everything works fine initially, but if I refresh the home page, the user becomes null.

This is what my [...nextauth].js looks like.

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import axios from "axios";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",

      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "justin" },
        password: {label: "Password",type: "password",placeholder: "******"},
      },

      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const url = req.body.callbackUrl.split("/auth")[0];
        const { username, password } = credentials;
        const user = await axios({
          url: `${url}/api/user/login`,
          method: "POST",
          data: {
            username: username,
            password: password,
          },
          "content-type": "application/json",
        })
          .then((res) => {
            return res.data;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            if (err.response.data) {
              throw new Error(err.response.data);
            } else {
              return null;
            }
            return null;
          });
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],

  callbacks: {
    jwt: ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }

      return token;
    },
    session: ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.user = token.user;
      }

      return session;
    },
  },

  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    newUser: "/auth/register",
  },
});
```

and this is what my /home route looks like

```
import Card from "@/components/card/Card";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styles from "./home.module.css";
import { Ubuntu } from "@next/font/google";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const ubuntu = Ubuntu({ weight: "500", subsets: ["cyrillic"] });
const getData = async (id) => {
  const res = await fetch({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/api/note/getall",
    method: "POST",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    data: {
      id: id,
    },
  });
  if (!res.ok) {
    console.log(id);
    throw new Error("Unable  to fetch");
  } else {
    return res.json();
    console.log(res);
  }
};

function home() {
  const colors = ["#E9F5FC", "#FFF5E1", "#FFE9F3", "#F3F5F7"];
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  const rc = colors[random];
  const [pop, setPop] = useState("none");
  const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const getDataa = async () => {
    console.log(user)
    const data = await getData(user._id);
    console.log(data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      alert(user)
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <header>
        <h3 className={ubuntu.className}>
          Hello, <br /> {user?.username}!
        </h3>
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
      </header>

      <div className={styles.nav}>
        <h1 className={ubuntu.className}>Notes</h1>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.section}>
        <div className={styles.inner}>
          {/*           {data &&
            data.map((e) => (
              <Card
                rawData={e}
                color={colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]}
              />
            ))} */}
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="new"></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default home;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this `component` to your *App.js* file :

```js
function Auth({ children }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { status } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      router.push("/sign-in");
    },
  });

  if (status === "loading") {
    return <div>Loading ...</div>;
  }
  return children;
}
```

Now in your *App* function instead of returning `<Component {...pageProps} />` you check first if the `component` has `auth` property, so you wrapp it with `<Auth>` to ensure that every component that requires session will only mount when the session finishes loading (that's why the user is `null` because the session is still loading)

```js
{
  Component.auth ? (
    <Auth>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Auth>
  ) : (
    <Component {...pageProps} />
  );
}
```

finally you add `.auth = {}` to every page in whitch you want the session to be defined (Home in your case)

```js
const Home = () => {
//....
}
Home.auth = {};
```

This also helps to redirect user to `/sign-in` page if the session is expired

Answer (score 1):

This code seems like it would create a problem / race-condition since you're mixing two different async promise handling styles:

```
const user = await axios({
  url: `${url}/api/user/login`,
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  },
  "content-type": "application/json",
})
  .then((res) => {
    return res.data;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    if (err.response.data) {
      throw new Error(err.response.data);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    return null;
  });
return user;
```

**It should either be this:**

```
try {
  const user = await axios({
    url: `${url}/api/user/login`,
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      username: username,
      password: password,
    },
    "content-type": "application/json",
  });
  return user.data;
} catch (err) {
  if (err.response.data) {
    throw new Error(err.response.data);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Or this:**

```
axios({
  url: `${url}/api/user/login`,
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    username: username,
    password: password,
  },
  "content-type": "application/json",
}).then((res) => {
  return res.data;
}).catch((err) => {
  if (err.response.data) {
    throw new Error(err.response.data);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
  return null;
});
```